# Programmatically Dismiss UIDocumentInteractionController OpenInMenu?

Tags: iphone

I am having much difficulty being able to dismiss (programmatically) my UIDocumentInteractionController's OpenIn Menu (Using the appropriate - dismissMenuWhatever method from the docs).  I just can't seem to get it to work.  Does anybody have any suggestions?  Maybe I have an inadequate intelligence level?  I am beginning to question the meaning of life.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are calling `dimissMenuAnimated:` on the right UIDocumentInteractionController. Maybe post some code if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: If I say, do this:
[docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES]
[docController dismissMenuAnimated:YES];  // doesn't seem to do anything...

nothing happens.

Comment: docController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:theURL] retain];
 docController.delegate = self;
 [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
 [docController dismissMenuAnimated:YES];  // doesn't seem to do anything...

That's the code.